# iOS - Getting a weird error: unrecognized selector sent to instance on a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-controls, unrecognized-selector

**Introduction**

In my current application I have a UITableView which holds custom cell objects. The custom UIViewCellObjects are simply subclassed from the standard UITableViewCell class. The custom cells holds information about running background uploads, and updates them with things like percentage done and so on.

The custom cell objects listens to NSNotifications from upload processes running in the background, and when they get a relevant notification, they simply update their own view controls with the new information (such as upload percentage).

Now when an upload process is done, I re-order the array of active upload objects and reload the tableview like this:

```
-(void) uploadFinished: (NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

NSNumber *uploadID = [userInfo valueForKey:@"uploadID"];

if (uploadID.integerValue == uploadActivity.uploadID)
{   
    [[ApplicationActivities getSharedActivities] markUploadAsFinished:uploadActivity];
    [parentTable reloadData];

    [self setUploadComplete];
}
}
```

Now this method takes place in the tableviewcell objects, and as you can see they call their owning UITableView to reload the data right after the array is sorted. The *markUploadAsFinished* method simply re-orders the array so any newly finished upload is put at the top, so it will appear this way in the UITableView.

**The Problem**

Now the problem I'm having is that when this method is called, I *sometimes* get the following error:
*'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance*

I do not get it all the time, sometimes the entire process runs fine and finished uploads appear in the start of the UItableview, and at other seemingly random times it fails. I don't really have a clue what's going on here.

The custom cells are loaded from a .NIB file like this:

```
    UploadCell *cell = [activeUploadsTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UploadProgressCell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UploadCellView" owner:self options:nil];

    cell = customCell;
}
```

Is there anyone who might have a clue about what's going on here?

**EDIT**

First of all, I have tracked down this error to appear right at the line where:
reloadData

is called inside of the custom cell objects.

Furthermore, it seems that the instance it sends methods to can change. I just got this error too:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I really have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: Where do you set the `dataSource` of your table view? It seems to be set to a `CALayer` instance when it fails.

Comment: The datasource of the tableview is set in a .nib file named "ActiveUploads". This .nib file simply contains a UIView containing the UItableview itself. The UITableView datasource + delegate is then set to the files owner of .nib file, and the files owner is a UIViewController which handles the creation you saw above.

Comment: Have you run with zombies enabled?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but it seems worth pointing out: If you have more uploads than cells fit on one screen, there may be no cell tracking the upload, hence no one will invoke `markUploadAsFinished` in the `ApplicationActivities` object. This may or may not become a problem in the future, depending on what `markUploadAsFinished` does.

Comment: Ah yes good catch, this could become a bit of a problem. MarkUploadAsFinished is a method which takes the uploadActivity object in points to and re-orders it in the uploads internal array so it bumps to the top of the tableview. I don't suppose there's any real way around this? Perhaps it would be better to just let the cells stay in their original position anyway, as to not confuse the user when they are looking at the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> '-[CALayer tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

You've got a bad pointer. It looks like your table's data source is being released while the table still exists. The table doesn't retain its data source because that could create a retain cycle. If you don't take care to keep the data source around while the table is using it, the table will can up with a pointer to an object that no longer exists. In this case, it looks like a CALayer object is subsequently being created at the same address. When the table later sends its "data source" a message to get the number of rows, that message is delivered to the layer, which (obviously) doesn't have a `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method, and the error results.

Comment: Aha! So thats the reason! well as you said I did figure out that the reason was a bad pointer, although I still werent sure of the underlying cause, but this clears it up :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to me you running the upload process method in background i think other thread than main thread. And according to my knowledge   when you deal with UIKIT objects you have ruin  on main thread.

But these problem  not occur every time because some time you switch to other thread to main thread so its working fine and some time not. so that problem occur

Comment: Thanks, but I already fixed this problem :) I will make a post about it as soon as Stackoverflow allows me to answer on my own question :) It was not because of thread-safety problems as the underlying upload objects makes use of the standard NSURLConnection asynchronous method, which deals with synchronization back to the main-thread.